# How to enable editing for QTableWidget

Tags: qt, widget

I'm using QTableWidget as view widget and QTableWidgetItem as items. How to enable editing for specific QTableWidgetItem cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the QTableWidget is enabled, you just set the correct flags on the QTableWidgetItem.

```
Qt::ItemFlags flags = item->flags();
flags = bEnable ? flags | Qt::ItemIsEditable : flags & ~Qt::ItemIsEditable;
item->setFlags(flags);
```